# performing addition of several columns of a table in idiorm

Tags: idiorm

Any ideas on how to perform addition of several columns in idiorm query

I want get the value of alias 'Due' n 'TotDue' as an addition of those specified columns,but i keep on getting a fatal Error
any assistance i shall realy appreciate;
This is my sample query ;

```
$d = ORM::for_table('transaction_s')
                        ->select_many(array('ACCT_TYPE'=>'transaction_s.TRANS_TYP',
                         'ADate'=>'transaction_s.ACCTDATE',
                         'Str'=>'accounts_master.PHYS_ADDRESS',
                         'Zone'=>'accounts_master.ZONE_ID',
                         'Name'=>'customers.CUSTOMER_NAME',
                         'Address'=>'customers.POST_ADDRESS',
                         'TelNo'=>'customers.TEL_NO',
                         'AcctNo'=>'transaction_s.ACCT_NO',
                         'smscost'=>'transaction_s.INT_AMOUNT',
                         'Due'=>'(transaction_s.water_DUE+transaction_s.METER_RENT+transaction_s.SEWER+
                                 transaction_s.Conserve+transaction_s.INT_AMOUNT+transaction_s.BIN_HIRE)',

                                 'TotalDue' =>'(transaction_s.water_DUE+transaction_s.METER_RENT+transaction_s.SEWER
                                         +transaction_s.Conserve+transaction_s.PREVBAL
                                         +transaction_s.INT_AMOUNT+transaction_s.BIN_HIRE)',
                         'OutStanding'=>'transaction_s.water_OUTSTANDING'
                         )
                     ->inner_join('accounts_master', 'customers.CUSTOMER_NO = accounts_master.CUSTOMER_NO')
                     ->inner_join('customers', 'customers.CUSTOMER_NO = accounts_master.CUSTOMER_NO')
                     ->find_many();
```

Comment: Can you add the complete error and the generated query?